# 403 forbidden issue when importing WSDL in UFT

Tags: web-services, hp-uft

I have a WSDL which is retrieving all available web services when I try to import from SOAP UI, where as I am getting '403-forbidden-Couldn't download' issue if I try to fetch the webs services using same WSDL in HP - UFT tool.

What could be the cause. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Sounds like you may not be providing your authentication details correctly?

Comment: Thanks Dave. But can you please suggest how I do authenticate in UFT for importing the WebServices.